# Add java rules in sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube

I want to add customized java rules in sonarqube. I have googled it and found that we need to make a pluggin for that. But can't find any proper link describing to make the rule. Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow "[Writing Custom Java Rules 101](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Writing+Custom+Java+Rules+101)", which describes how to make a sonar-`packaging-maven-plugin` artifact.

> When implementing a rule, there is always a minimum of 3 distinct files to create:
>
> - A test file, which contains Java code used as input data for testing the rule
> - A test class, which contains the rule's unit test
> - A rule class, which contains the implementation of the rule.

As mentioned in "[Custom Rules for Java](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Custom+Rules+for+Java)", To go further, you can explore a sample plugin containing other custom rules.
This project can be [browsed](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-custom-rules-examples/tree/master/java-custom-rules) or [downloaded](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-custom-rules-examples/archive/master.zip).